# Как убирать input и показывать в зависимости от выбранного radio с OnClick

Tags: javascript

```
<input type="radio" value="yes" name="radio" onclick="show_hide('visible')"  > Да
<input type="radio" value="no" name="radio"onclick="show_hide('hidden')"checked="checked"> Нет
```

Как сделать чтобы при клике на show_hide('visible')показывался <input type='text' name='r2d2'/>.
а при клике show_hide('hidden') он скрывался

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/XUteU/1/ — вы это имели ввиду?

```
<form name="XForm" method="post">
    <label><input type="radio" value="yes" name="radio"/> Да</label>
    <label><input type="radio" value="no" name="radio" checked="checked"/> Нет</label>
    <input type="text" name="r2d2" style="display: none" />
</form>

<script>
function show_hide(visibility/**string*/){
    // your logic
}

document.forms.XForm.addEventListener('click', function (evt/**Event*/){
    var el = evt.target;
    if( el.name == 'radio' ){
        // call user function
        show_hide(el.value == 'yes' ? 'visible' : 'hidden');

        // show/hide input[type="text"] element
        el.form.r2d2.style.display = (el.value == 'yes') ? '' : 'none';
    }
}, false);
</script>
```

Comment: добавил кнопку submit name=aded
почему проверка не может выполнится?
<br>
<?if(isset($_POST['added'])) {

 $gf=$_POST['radio'];
 $df=$_POST['r2d2']; 
 echo $gf. "eto r2d2=$df"; 
 }
 else {echo "gg";}
?>
просто потом надо будет  что выбранно добавить на сервер...

Comment: Ничего не понял, какая проверка? Если в php script то, в моем примере форма отправляется GET-запросом, исправил на POST

Comment: а как где это объясняется  что GET.
не нравится когда такое спрашивают но мне очень надо разобраться в javascript но в программирование я "тютю"...скажите пожалуйста что нужно знать для составления данной формы?заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: У формы есть атрибут `method`, подробнее тут — http://htmlbook.ru/html/form

Comment: а если затронуть всё таки JS?

Comment: А можно по подробнее, что вы подразумеваете под завернуть в JS?

Comment: "скажите пожалуйста что нужно знать для составления данной формы?заранее большое спасибо!" конкретно javascript'a!

Answer (score 0):

Например, можно [так](http://jsfiddle.net/nYJcL/):

```
<input id="yes" type="radio" value="yes" name="radio" > Да
<input id="no" type="radio" value="no" name="radio" checked="checked"> Нет
<input type='text' name='r2d2'/>

$("#no").click(function(){$("input:last").attr('hidden', 'hidden');});
$("#yes").click(function(){$("input:last").removeAttr('hidden');});
```

Comment: беда...как только документ открывается по умолчанию input виден

Comment: Задайте для инпута, который не должен быть виден по умолчанию CSS свойство display:none;

в коде самого инпута:
 <input type='text' name='r2d2' style='display:none;' />